# Proguard Error : Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'

Tags: android

I am trying to build app using ProGuard in Android Studio 2.2.3 but I am getting below error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Comment: Maybe invalidate caches aswell

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `proguard-project.txt` file in your project? 
If so can you post its content? Also, you can try running '`gradle --stacktrace assemble --debug`' for more details about your error.